# django 2.1 HTML form submitting to db error

Tags: django

i am trying to post the data from html form to my db, however i get the error that the url does not exist. what am trying to do is later on turn the test form into dynamic add fields using HTML and Jquery rather than using formset for ease UI designing and handle it in dango back end.

also note that am assigning the foreign key which is the startup_name by passing it through the url to test view.

the code is as following:

models.py:

```
     class Startup(models.Model):
         author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
         startup_name = models.CharField('Startup Name', max_length = 32, null = False, blank = False)

     class Team (models.Model):
         str_team = models.ForeignKey(Startup, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
         name = models.CharField('Name',max_length = 32, null = False, blank = False)
         position = models.CharField('Title/Position', max_length = 32, null = False, blank = False)
         qualification = models.CharField('Degrees/Qualifications', max_length=32,null=False,blank=False)
```

views.py:

```
     def create_startupform(request):
         if request.method == 'POST':
             form = startupform(request.POST)
             if form.is_valid():
                 result = form.save(commit=False)
                 result.author = request.user
                 result.save()
                 return redirect('test', startup_id = result.pk)
         else:
             form = startupform()
         return render(request, 'str_name.html', {'form': form})

     def test (request, startup_id):
         e = Startup.objects.values('startup_name')

         if request.method == 'POST':
             na = request.POST.get("name")
             po = request.POST.get("position")
             qu = request.POST.get("qualification")

             ref = Team(name = na, position = po, qualification = qu, str_team = e)
             ref.save()
             return redirect('str_dashboard')
         return render(request, 'test.html')
```

forms.py:

```
     class startupform(forms.ModelForm):
         class Meta:
             model = Startup
             fields = ('startup_name',)
             widgets = {
                 'startup_name': forms.TextInput(attrs = {'class':'form-control'}),
             }

         def clean(self):
             super ( ).clean ( )
             startup_name = self.cleaned_data.get ( 'startup_name' )
             startup_qs = Startup.objects.filter ( startup_name = startup_name )
             if startup_qs.exists ( ):
                 raise forms.ValidationError ( 'This Startup Already Exist!' )
```

test.html:

```
     <form id="add-extra" class="form" method="post" action = "{% url 'test' %}">{% csrf_token %}
<div class="form-row profile-row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-12">
        <hr />
        <h4>Startup Core Team</h4>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Position</th>
                                    <th>Qualification</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="candidate_name" /></td>
                                    <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="position"/></td>
                                    <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="qualification"/></td>
                                    <td><button class="btn btn-primary d-lg-flex align-items-lg-center" type="button" style="margin-top: 4px;margin-left: 15px;background-color: rgb(24,130,7);"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr></tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-md-12 content-right"><button class="btn btn-primary text-center border rounded d-lg-flex justify-content-lg-end align-items-lg-center form-btn" type="post" style="margin-left: 1040px;padding: 6px;">SAVE </button></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

URLS:

```
     from django.urls import path
     from . import views



     urlpatterns = [

         path ( 'str_dashboard/' , views.str_dashboard , name = 'str_dashboard' ),
         path ( 'create_startupform/' , views.create_startupform, name = 'create_startupform' ),
         path('test/', views.test, name='test'),

       ]
```

Error:

```
     Page not found (404)
     Request Method:    GET
     Request URL:   http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/
     Using the URLconf defined in sourcing.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
```

Comment: i have resolved the error by changing request.POST.get("name") to request.POST.get["name"], however, i still dont get my data in the database. i am using postgres database. appreciate anybodies help in this regards

Comment: Why you are not  using model form for saving data . You can easily design your form with bootstrap classes its very easy.

Comment: i tried to add dynamic fields for a formset but it is complicating things and this method seem simpler and more straight forward

Comment: in your `test.html` i dont see the `form` tag closing, and I dont see `{% csrf_token  %}` either. And please try to make clean code using `PEP8` because people reading nicely formatted code often think "it's a good professional".

Comment: the csrf token in html is after the form tag for html, plus this is an html form submitting to django back end, refer to the tutorials i followed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Ov1Yd1uCuA&t=814s

Answer (score 0):

You are trying an url which is not in the urls.py:

```py
     urlpatterns = [
         ...
         path('test/<int:startup_id>/', views.test, name='test'),
         path('test/', views.test, name='test_base'),  # add this
       ]
```

The url 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/' won't match because it would need to have 'startup_id' attached with your urls.py.
http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/**1** would work.

If you do like i wrote above, make sure that your view is taking startup_id as optional. Or use another function for the call without startup_id.

Comment: i tried it but still cant get the data into database, i also updated the question

Comment: Sorry, what has changed? I can't find it. Is it the same error?

Comment: i changed the URL and the query in  createteamform view, i cant get the data submitted to db